# How to add annotation based on the value in bokeh

Tags: python-3.x, bokeh

I want to be able to display "NO DATA" when there is a value '0' in counts. For example for Strawberries, "NO DATA" should be displayed in the graph.

```
    from bokeh.io import show, output_file
    from bokeh.plotting import figure
    output_file("bar_basic.html")
    fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
    counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 0]
    p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=350, title="Fruit Counts")
    p.vbar(x=fruits, top=counts, width=0.9)
    p.y_range.start = 0
    show(p)
```

For example, for above data the graph should look like this:[example vbar with NO DATA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnOVV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the data with the count value '0' with Pandas. This new dataframe can be used to create another ColumnDataSource to use for the LabelSet to show the text 'NO DATA' in the figure.

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, LabelSet
import pandas as pd

output_file("bar_basic.html")
fruits = ['Apples', 'Pears', 'Nectarines', 'Plums', 'Grapes', 'Strawberries']
counts = [5, 3, 4, 2, 4, 0]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'fruits': fruits, 'counts': counts})
source = ColumnDataSource(df)
p = figure(x_range=fruits, plot_height=350, title="Fruit Counts")
p.vbar(x='fruits', top='counts', source=source, width=0.9)
df_nodata = df.loc[df['counts'] == 0]
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
df_nodata.loc[:, 'text'] = 'NO DATA'
source_nodata = ColumnDataSource(df_nodata)
labels = LabelSet(x='fruits', y=1, text='text', text_align='center', source=source_nodata)
p.add_layout(labels)
p.y_range.start = 0
show(p)
```